# An idiom to describe someone who thinks he/she is wiser than others

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

Is there an idiom in English to describe someone who thinks he/she is smarter/wiser than everyone else?

In Polish, we have an idiom, which literally translated, would sound like:

> He/she has eaten all minds

Comment: US=smarty-pants. UK=smart aleck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In English, a common term for such a person is "know-it-all", as in:

> Ever since Bob took that first-year philosophy course, he's acting like such a know-it-all.

Usually the phrase has a *slightly* negative connotation to it, because it implies that the person really *doesn't* know it all, but they might act arrogant as if they do know it all.

Comment: With typical Australian economy of language, Bob would be a "[know-all](http://dictionary.kids.net.au/word/know-all)". We don't like to waste syllables.

Answer (score 13):

There are numerous amusing English terms for such a person, including
• *[wiseacre](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wiseacre#Noun)* (“One who feigns knowledge or cleverness; an insolent upstart”),
• *[smarty-pants](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smarty_pants#Noun)* (“A smart aleck or know-it-all”),
• *[clever dick](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clever_dick)* (“(chiefly UK) A person who annoyingly tries too hard to impress with their cleverness”),
• *[smart aleck](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smart_aleck#Noun)* (“One who is pretentious about their own cleverness or knowledge; a know-it-all”, but also with senses  “One who is obnoxiously self-assured; a show off” and “One who is given to obnoxious or insolent humor; a wise guy”).

Some terms related to the above, but with slightly different meanings, include
• *[wiseass](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wiseass#Noun)* (“One who makes wisecracks, particularly in a sassy or cocky fashion”),
• *[smartass](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smartass#Noun)* (“(slang) One who is particularly insolent, who tends to make snide remarks or jokes”).

Comment: I go along with a couple of these but also see them being applied more so to a (how to describe this without using one of your words?) . . . person who always tries to crack a joke or make fun of someone.  (I was going to use "wisenheimer" but discovered it actually is a better word for the OP's intent than some others!) :-)

Comment: good, but they are not as poetic as 'eating all minds' ;)

Answer (score 10):

Though "know-it-all" is my #1 go-to phrase for that meaning, another expression with a smart-alecky negative connotation would be to refer to someone as "Einstein", as in:

**"*Einstein*, here, has all the answers!"**

Of course, the reference would be to Albert Einstein, the theoretical physicist:

[image]

Comment: Apparently, [the overall size and asymmetrical shape of Einstein’s brain were normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein's_brain), so he didn't have a [brain the size of a planet](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dummies+guide+to%22&oq=%22dummies+guide+to%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.34108642&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) after all. But +1 for the "snappiest" idiomatic usage here so far.

Answer (score 3):

How about:  "He[she] is full of himself[herself]"? That's a pretty common English idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the *wiser* aspect:

**Holier-than-thou**

Characterized by an attitude of moral superiority

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/holier-than-thou

Answer (score -3):

Charlatan is the word to describe such person

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  Can you please include a definition from a dictionary that describes the characteristics of a "Charlatan"?  That would be helpful to our users as they are from all over the world and not all words are known internationally.

Comment: I wouldn't use the word [_charlatan_](http://www.wordnik.com/words/charlatan) in the context the O.P. mentions unless I wanted to also imply a sense of dishonesty or delusion.