# More formal word for the chronic state of being in a snit

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This question relates to my previous question: [More formal word for "know-it-all"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355232/more-formal-word-for-know-it-all)

I would like to describe the general attitude of a particular witness, in my closing argument.  This will help me comment on her reliability as a witness.  She was very negative about everything, and came across as being in a snit about everything.  I need a word for this idea of being in a snit.  She was opposed to everything.  She got herself tied into contradictory knots because she was opposed to so many things.

The word could be an adjective describing her constant oppositional state.  Or it could be a word to mean the oppositional state itself.  It should show that it comes from a desire to show that everything the parent speaks, acts, dreams, or breathes is *wrong*.  That was her guiding principle.  But it was an emotional (visceral) thing for her.  She's too stupid to be analytical.

*Oppositional* doesn't work because two-year-olds are oppositional.  They say "no" to *everything*.  This person had a negative attitude only regarding whatever she thought the *parents* were saying or trying to accomplish.

The closest I've gotten so far is that she was pathologically anti-parent.  But I can't say "pathologically" in the closing argument.  I need a less offensive sounding word.

(Being in this perpetual snit affected her memory and her judgment.  She ended up speaking total nonsense.)

Comment: Its a shame that on most of the occasions when you could say "anal retentive" and be understood, you can't.

Comment: "Hypercritical" or "thin skinned"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She sounds like a [hostile witness](http://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=884), *technically an "adverse witness" in a trial who is found by the judge to be hostile (adverse) to the position of the party whose attorney is questioning the witness, even though the attorney called the witness to testify on behalf of his/her client.  When the attorney calling the witness finds that the answers are contrary to the legal position of his/her client or the witness becomes openly antagonistic, the attorney may request the judge to declare the witness to be "hostile" or "adverse." If the judge declares the witness to be hostile (i.e. adverse), the attorney may ask "leading" questions which suggest answers or are challenging to the testimony just as on cross examination of a witness who has testified for the opposition.*

Or at least [hostile](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hostile) .
*2.opposed in feeling, action, or character; antagonistic: 
hostile criticism.
3. characterized by antagonism.*

Comment: Your legal link was really helpful.  From it I got "openly antagonistic".  I might add "consistent."  I can use *hostile* sometimes, *hostile to the family*, and *antagonistic* sometimes.  //  In terms of standard practice here at ELU, I believe it's encouraged to include *both* links *and* definitions.  Sometimes people also include an example (not needed here, though).  I confess I sometimes omit the definitions, especially if I'm having trouble finding one that matches my own understanding of the word.  But you found satisfactory definitions.  Could you do a copy and paste into your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the defs.  I added the second part of the legal definition you found, because it was the best part.  Interestingly, the hearing officer did allow me to ask "Isn't it true" type questions of this witness.  I thought at the time it was just because she was a meandering answerer and he wanted to move things along -- but now I see there may have been a technical component to it as well.  Thank you for finding this.

Answer (score 2):

One word that immediately comes to my mind is [irascible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irascible): "becoming angry very easily; having a bad temper."  There's also one sense of "[contrary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrary)" that fits--"temperamentally unwilling to accept control or advice.

Answer (score 2):

***defensive***, as used in [MentalHelp.net](https://www.mentalhelp.net/advice/what-is-the-true-meaning-of-being-defensive/)

> Generally, when people talk about someone becoming **defensive** in the
>   context of a conversation, they are meaning that that someone is
>   engaging in emotionally **defensive** maneuvers designed to ward off their
>   having to experience some unwanted feeling or admit responsibility for
>   some disowned act. People who are acting **defensively** are essentially
>   trying to protect themselves from feeling a certain uncomfortable way,
>   and from viewing themselves as a failure or otherwise in a negative
>   light.

It sounds as though the person you describe has argued herself into a box and doesn't know how to get out of it.  She sees, rightly or wrongly, everything you say as an attack that she must defend herself and her professional reputation against.

defensive, [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/defensive)

> Very anxious to challenge or avoid criticism.

defensive, [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/defensive)

> Psychology: Constantly protecting oneself from criticism, exposure of
>   one's shortcomings, or other real or perceived threats to the
>   ego........
>
> Harriet Beecher Stowe, *Uncle Tom's Cabin*:  Dinah had heard, from
>   various sources, what was going on, and resolved to stand on defensive
>   and conservative ground,--mentally determined to oppose and ignore
>   every new measure, without any actual observable contest

.

Answer (score 1):

How about *chip on one's shoulder*?

> [*chip on one's shoulder*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chip?s=t):
> a disposition to quarrel [Dictionary.com]
>
> [*chip on (one's) shoulder*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/chip+on+shoulder): a habitually hostile or combative
> attitude [The Free Dictionary]

The witness in your question has a *chip on her shoulder*. Hard to deal with.

One might also characterize your witness as *pissed off at the world*. Also hard to deal with.

> [*pissed off*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pissed): very disgruntled, angry, or outraged [From The Free Dictionary]

As accurate as this might be, I'm not sure you could use it to characterize the witness in court, but *disgruntled* could work:

> [*disgruntled*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disgruntled?s=t):
> displeased and discontented; sulky; peevish [Dictionary.com]

It seems to me you could describe the witness as having a *chip on her shoulder*, as being *pissed off at the world* (maybe), or as being very *disgruntled*.

Comment: That's the right idea.  Might be hard to fit into a sentence.

Comment: @aparente001 I've edited my answer. See if you like it better. I think you could easily use any of these possibilities in a sentence. The first two are common idioms.

Comment: I am still leaning towards the *chip*.  (P___ off - formal?!)

Comment: @aparente001 No, not formal, but it fits well the person you are describing. Of the three, and given your context, I think *chip* fits best. *Disgruntled* also works, but it's not as colorful. How are you doing?

Comment: I think the *chip* is about at the same level of formality as the *snit*.  *Hostile* and *antagonistic*, and their associated nouns, are what I'm going to aim for in my document.  But the meaning was right on target.

Comment: @aparente While it’s not specifically formal, I wouldn’t think there’s anything _informal_, either, about saying something like, “It is clear from her consistent antagonism towards the parents that she has somewhat of a chip on her shoulders regarding [them/the upbringing of their child/their XYZ]”. In an otherwise quite formal context, it would merely come off as neutral to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the example sentence. My comment, "No, not formal," referred to *pissed off at the world*. I agree completely with your thoughts on the formality/informality of *chip*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Okay, I'll put it in the draft and see how it looks.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your protagonist was [vexatiously](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vexatious) [obstructive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obstructive). The use of vexatious is not the legal but the more geneneral one

> Causing or tending to cause annoyance, frustration or worry

You could also claim that she expressed [negativity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/negativity) towards you and your opinions and experience since she appears to have expressed criticism of you.

Comment: *Obstructive* is a word I can use for another person in the cast of characters.