# Is *holy*, used sarcastically, potentially offensive?

Tags: religion, tone

Do I need to replace *holy* with *sacred* in the following formal writing, because a Christian reader might take offense?

> The poor survey design and irresponsible use of the results left the parents and their guests with the impression that the district was looking for a way to back up its positions with some kind of data, any kind of data.  Questions posed about the **holy “data”** were seen as obstructions of the 504 process.

---

Description of the survey: the teachers were asked to fill out a google doc.  For each accommodation on the child's 504 plan, each teacher was supposed to say, "yes, should continue to be provided," or "no, etc.," and there was an optional comment field.  There were three major problems with this survey: (1) Data *should* have been taken on whether providing a particular accommodation seemed to result in fewer incidents of misbehavior, or a better rate of e.g. handing in homework (the child has OCD and hoards completed homeworks in his knapsack; also I can prevent homework assignments from being ripped up or stuffed in the toilet by reducing the repetitive math exercises); (2) the parents and the child weren't asked for their input; (3) the comments revealed that the teachers had not really understood most of the accommodations as written, and many of them were being judged without their having been actually provided.  (Note, I would have loved to meet with the teachers to explain things, but I haven't been permitted to do so.)

I hope this is the kind of context that folks were hoping for, and I hope it wasn't too long.

---

There was some doubt about this use of *holy* being understandable.  Here's the definition: "4. Regarded as deserving special respect or reverence" (freedictionary.com).  Add some sarcasm and what you get is *not-to-be-questioned*.

Comment: Need more context to be sure. "Blessed" may be a better word.

Comment: @EL_DON - *Blessed* is more satisfying than *sacred*.  But I'm concerned about the same thing, maybe it would be potentially offensive to some? // What additional context would you like?  I was afraid I was giving too much.  Perhaps the intro to this question would help: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/355232/112436

Comment: If you can tell us what *holy data* refers to, we may be able to help you.

Comment: @EL_DON provided more context.

Comment: @Mick -  provided more context.

Comment: So there's no religious context? In that case, using the term *holy* would just cause confusion. If this 'data' is not to be questioned (by laymen), then it could be called *sacrosanct*. Anyone with an entrenched viewpoint should get the meaning readily enough.

Comment: @Mick - I was trying to use *holy* sarcastically, to convey that the people who wrote the survey were using it as something sacrosanct.  Is your English of the British variety?  I didn't think that just understanding this use of "holy" would be a problem.  I was only concerned about how a religious person might take it.

Comment: If the data is missing some crucial pieces, you could call it *holey* instead.

Comment: @DavidHandelman - I noticed that too!

Comment: Holy data? Holy moly, I suppose that 'data etched in tablets of stone' is out of the question, what?

Comment: I am a Brit. Using the term *holy* ought not to be considered offensive in the UK, although some Muslims might object. It is more likely to cause confusion in which case any intended sarcasm may be lost.

Comment: I am British too. I probably wouldn't use it in front of the Pope or the Archbishop of Canterbury, but it is not something for which I would feel accountable to any religious police.

Comment: It's generally not offensive, but there are folks who will be offended by anything.  And, in the US, I'm not sure the reader would understand the intended meaning.  "Approved" or "endorsed" might be a better choice (or check synonyms for "bless").

Comment: Anyone over-sensitive enough to find _holy_ used in this way offensive would almost certainly also take offence at _sacred_, _blessed_, and even _sacrosanct_. I'd advise against trying to please such people.

Comment: Given the new context, it sounds fine. The point you're making is that the data are not to be questioned, or that some people have inferred that this is the case, right? Holy or sacred should convey that without offending. I like sacred better but I think that's subjective.

Comment: When they take offense, you just need to position yourself as even more religious than the offended person is. People were making graven images of data, which you rightfully called out as blasphemous, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any value in characterizing the "data" (sarcasm noted) as "holy", "sacred", ... I see no grounds for religious objection, but such words will most likely result in a defensive response not conducive to your desired outcome. Why not stick to the facts (as you see them) without rendering judgment:

> The poor survey design and irresponsible use of the results left the
>   parents and their guests with the impression that the district was
>   looking for a way to back up its positions with some kind of data, any
>   kind of data. *Legitimate questions posed about the design of the survey and the use of its results* were seen as obstructions of the 504 process.

Comment: *Legitimate* is a good addition.  I simplified the last sentence to "Legitimate questions were seen as obstructions of the 504 process."  Since it's still the same paragraph and the paragraph is short, I figured it will be clear what the questions would have been about.

Comment: In the context of the question you ask, there is no slightest difference between "holy" and "sacred"

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I agree. This has nothing to with anything I've said, right?

Comment: @Richard Kayser I certainly think not… I do think that 'holy “data” ' should be ' "holy" data' and that's nothing to do with what you or I said before…

Beneath all the above, though, a dedicated follower of any faith might very well find "holy" or "sacred" or anything like them offensive outside a truly religious context, as you hinted… and anyway, offense is almost always taken, rather than given.